# saving a session variable from a form

Tags: php, session, variables

need help saving the POST method within a session variable from the form I have tried using

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $favcolour = $_POST["favColour"];
    $_SESSION["favColour"] = $favcolour; 
    ?>

    <form action="exercise3.php" method="POST">
    <label for="fColour">Favourite Colour: </label><input type="text" 
    name="fColour" id="fcolour">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need to then echo the variable on the following page

```
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    echo $_SESSION["fColour"];
    }
```

Comment: You set it as $_SESSION["favColour"] but echoing as $_SESSION["fColour"]; Name must be same in session variable

Answer (score 2):

You set it as 
`$_SESSION["favColour"]` but echoing as `$_SESSION["fColour"]`;
Name must be same in session variable

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $favcolour = $_POST["favColour"];
    $_SESSION["favColour"] = $favcolour;   //You have set your session in favColour variable
?>

<form action="exercise3.php" method="POST">
    <label for="fColour">Favourite Colour: </label><input type="text" 
    name="fColour" id="fcolour">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### Your exercise3.php code.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    echo $_SESSION["favColour"];  //Get the session value. The variable name should be same as what you have set.
}
```